# Is ZFC interpretable in bisimilar ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

If we add a primitive binary relation $\sim$ to denote "bisimilarity" relation. Remove the axiom of Extensionality from axioms of $\sf ZFC$, and add:

**Bisimilarity:** $\forall x \, (x \sim x) \\ \begin{align} \forall x \forall y \,  (x \sim y \iff &\forall u \in x \exists w \in y \, (w \sim u) \land \\&\forall w \in y \, \exists u \in x \, (u \sim w)) \end{align} $

Define: $\operatorname {Set}(x) \iff \forall a,b \in x: a \neq b \to a \not \sim b $

We alter the axiom of Power sets to:

**Power':** $\forall x \exists y: \operatorname {Set}(y) \land \forall z \subseteq x \exists {\sf z} \in y\, (  {\sf z }\sim z)$

**Infinity':** $\exists x: \operatorname {Set} (x) \land  0 \in x \land \\\forall y \in x \exists z \in x: \forall m (m \in z \leftrightarrow m=y)$

Also replace **Replacement** by  **[Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement#Collection)**, and keep other axioms of $\sf ZFC$.

Add the following axioms:

**Reduction:** $\forall a \exists \alpha: \operatorname {Set}(\alpha): a \sim \alpha$

**De-Extensionality:** $\forall x \not \exists y: \forall {\sf x}  (x \equiv {\sf x} \to {\sf x} \in y)$

Where $\equiv$ is coextensionality relation, i.e. having the same members.

> Is $\sf ZFC$ interpretable in this system?

Comment: I'm not a Set Theorist, so don't quote me on this, but I think Dana Scott's 1966 paper on Extensionality showed that ZF without it is provably consistent in Zermelo set theory alone. That is, no!

Comment: Just for curiosity, what motivates your question?

Comment: @Hanul Jeon, In reality an approach to NF through bisimulation as an alternative to Extensionality, but I need to understand it first in ZF context, since models of NFU can be retrieved through automorphisms from models of ZF, so I need to make sure that it works in ZF.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Yes. That is the case when the usual Replacement axiom schema is used. But, when Collection is used instead, then it can interpret full ZFC. But, the situation here is different.

Comment: If understanding bisimulation is the only purpose, I would rather suggest Aczel's *Non-well-founded set* or Harvey Friedman's interpretation of $\mathsf{ZF}$ to $\mathsf{IZF}$.

Comment: @HanulJeon, I need to violate Extensionality, that's important. Aczel's AFA actually strengthens Extensionality, Harvey's is done in a weaker logic. Also Dana Scott's approach doesn't allow a proper class of Atoms. Also there are the works of Gandy, Boffa. But, all those though related yet they don't satisfy what I need.